# In an Angular rxjs service, how to return an observable out of a property of the return object of HttpClient.get

Tags: angular, rxjs

In an angular service, I would like the method to return a property of the data instead of all the data.

I tried this:

```
export class RecipeService {

  private recipesUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/recipes';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getRecipes (): Observable<Recipe[]> {
    return this.http.get<Recipe[]>(this.recipesUrl).pipe((data) => {
       return of(data['recipes']);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: You should review documentation for [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). pipe() does not take an argument of the data stream, you pass operators that can take the observable stream as an argument.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky if I understand right what you wrote, then to implement my own version of pluck(), I would just have to slightly modify the "takeEveryNth" operator function presented in the "Build Your Own Operators Easily" section of the doc you linked to (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). correct ?

Comment: You don’t need to implement your own version of pluck. The answer provided is a great way to approach your issue. I wanted to provided documentation of using pipe() in general as your question was attempting to use pipe() incorrectly.

Comment: I have validated the given answer. I should have better worded my comment with a "if I ever wanted to implement my own version". Since you pointed my mistake of believing that the operator gets an argument of the data (instead of an observable stream), then I was curious as of how I would have to implement such operator if pluck wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the [pluck](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/pluck.html) operator.

```
getRecipes (): Observable<Recipe[]> {
    return this.http
        .get<Recipe[]>(this.recipesUrl)
        .pipe(pluck('recipes'));
}
```

Comment: FYI ... pluck has been deprecated.  https://devdocs.io/rxjs/api/operators/pluck